# How I could know when the modal animation is finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using the modal plugin from twitter-bootstrap and i'd like to know the time that the modal spends in appear to show an alert before.

In this example that I did you can see what I mean: **http://tinker.io/e69ff/6**

**HTML**

```
<button id="mod" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    hello
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
      Hello all!
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
     $("#mod").click(function(){ 
        $('#navigate-away').modal('show');
     });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#mod{
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

---

But there's no event for this in the documentation... There is a way to handle this? Any tip or advice would be appreciated.

*If you need more info, let me know and i'll edit the post.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in the docs, you use the shown event to know when animations have completed:

"shown: This event is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user (will wait for css transitions to complete)."

```
$('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
  // do something… 
})
```